Relocate Toolbar in DevExtreme File Manager
I would like to move the toolbar in the file manager out of from under the file-manager wrapper. I have researched and you are able to do this with the HTML editor, but I wanted to know if it was possible to do this with the file manager.
I tried the following HTML Editor Relocate Toolbar just to see if this was a universal option...it is not.
https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Documentation/24_2/Guide/UI_Components/HtmlEditor/Toolbar/Relocate_the_Toolbar/
Any one have success with this?
